# Facebook playable ads with phaser

Tags: node.js, html5-canvas, xmlhttprequest, phaser-framework, facebook-ads

I am trying to make Facebook playable ad using Phaser3.60 but the problem is that Facebook block XMLHttpRequest which is used internally in phaser load to load images and sounds.
do do any one know a way to images to phaser without using its loader and without using XMLHttpResquest.
[image: Error I got when uploading the ad]

I tried to use  imageLoadType: "HTMLImageElement" but it also gives me the same error, I dont know if facebook detect the XMLHttpRequest in the Phaser.min or in the game code.

Comment: Just a question, did you try to continue and test the app in tne PreviewTool, as stated in the Warning message? I assume this warning is issued, because its only a static code analysis, so the phaser library, contain such calls, but if you don't use a feature, that uses XMLHttpRequest, it should still work. That's why they give you the option to teste it with the preview tool.

Comment: I am using a ZIP file to make it, the Facebook playable preview but this issue appears when I want to upload the game on Facebook business suit, the ad appear but this issue prevent me to upload it

Comment: Oh I see, I don't know much about Facebook Ads. Thank you for clearing this up.  hmm sounds tricky, I will see if I think of something.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it would really helps me <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution for your specific problem, but after some tinkering, I learn abit about facebooks playable ads.

> **Disclaimer:** First of all, I was not able the get the `zip` version to run.*(not on the preview Tool and not even on a real campain)*

With a single file `index.html`, with all the data inlined *(just under the 2MB limit)*, I can upload the application and get the same Warning,

[image: screenshot after upload]

**BUT** after I click the Application (what executes `FbPlayableAd.onCTAClick()`, as mentioned in the yellow highlighted part), then the **Done** Button is activated, and I can deploy the ad.

[image: screenshot after CTA click]

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helped a lot, thank you <3